# Error can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator while calculating population standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am trying to calculate the population standard deviation of my data frame in python. I am using the function `statistics.pstdev(df)` by importing the `statistics` library. I have exclude all the non float columns from my dataset and it contain only float data columns. But I am getting the following error while executing:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-f8b494b6fd29> in <module>()
      1 import statistics
----> 2 statistics.pstdev(tot2)

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in pstdev(data, mu)
    664 
    665     """
--> 666     var = pvariance(data, mu)
    667     try:
    668         return var.sqrt()

/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in pvariance(data, mu)
    635     if n < 1:
    636         raise StatisticsError('pvariance requires at least one data point')
--> 637     T, ss = _ss(data, mu)
    638     return _convert(ss/n, T)
    639 

/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in _ss(data, c)
    533     """
    534     if c is None:
--> 535         c = mean(data)
    536     T, total, count = _sum((x-c)**2 for x in data)
    537     # The following sum should mathematically equal zero, but due to rounding

/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in mean(data)
    310     if n < 1:
    311         raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
--> 312     T, total, count = _sum(data)
    313     assert count == n
    314     return _convert(total/n, T)

/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in _sum(data, start)
    146     for typ, values in groupby(data, type):
    147         T = _coerce(T, typ)  # or raise TypeError
--> 148         for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
    149             count += 1
    150             partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n

/usr/lib/python3.6/statistics.py in _exact_ratio(x)
    228         return (x, None)
    229     msg = "can't convert type '{}' to numerator/denominator"
--> 230     raise TypeError(msg.format(type(x).__name__))
    231 
    232 

TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator
```

Comment: What is `tot2`? Please show a [mre].

Comment: tot2 is the name of  the data frame whose standard deviation I need to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass one *column* of the dataframe to `statistics.pstdev`, instead of the whole dataframe.

When treating a dataframe as an iterable, this will result in the column names (which are strings), not in the values of a column. That's why you get this error.

So, assuming that you want to calculate the standard deviation of a column named `"values"`, you should use

```
statistics.pstdev(tot2["values"])
```

Alternatively, just use the [DataFrame.std](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) method to get the standard deviation of all columns at once:

```
tot2.std(axis=0)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response, but  tot2.std(axis=0) gives the standard deviation of the all columns  separately in other words it is giving standard deviation of a sample data. BUT I want the standard deviation of whole data frame as one value which is called as standard deviation of a population

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what exactly you want to achieve, with an example.